# RedirectMatch 301 Wildcards Without Variables at the End

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

How do You do a re-direct a group of pages with a wildcard that doesn't attach the variables at the end? For example, the .htaccess code below:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /general/old_events_page.php(.*) http://mysite.org/events
```

Yields this:

mysite.org/events?id=749&friendly=1&date=20090308

But I just want it to go to http://mysite.org/events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^general/old_events_page\.php$ /events? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use RewriteCond + RewriteRule to achieve this.

**RewriteCond** evaluates the conditions for which the rule applies

**RewriteRule** is the rule itself

Anyway... This should the trick;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /general/old_events_page.php
RewriteRule .? /events$1? [R=301,L]
```